# How to get WCF Interface Version of UserNameAuthenticaton

Tags: c#, authentication, wcf, client-server, versioning

I have a WCF server/client structure, which gets a new way for authentication.

`serviceHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;`

There are two versions:

- Server Version 1.0 Supports Authentication 1.0
- Server Version 2.0 Supports Authentication 2.0

Both Server Versions supports username and password. The client needs to know, which user should be used. The new client should support both Authentication methods.

- Client 2.0 --> Server 1.0
- Client 2.0 --> Server 2.0

Is there any information available, to get the service version of the server before the authentication process? The client should select the compatible method depended on the version of the server.

One idea was to use a mex data with the version infos inside the url.

Comment: A token get return during authentication. The token has properties described at following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#token-formats

Answer (score 0):

A service's endpoint identity is a value generated from the service Web Services Description Language : WSDL. This value, propagated to any client, is used to authenticate the service.

You can verify communication in this way, as you can see [for examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/service-identity-and-authentication).